# Filtering a Wave

Tags: python

I am trying to write a function `filter_wave(wave,1)` and this will produce a new wave which is a smoothed version of the input wave. Following the rules below:

In the new wave, for every position `i`, it is the weighted sum of three positions of the original wave. Specifically, the new wave value in position `i` will be equal to

```
new_wave[i] = wave[i-1] * 0.2 + wave[i]*0.6 + wave[i+1]*0.2
```

some of the conditions:

- Let `len(wave)` be `L`. The above method will access `wave[-1]` and `wave[L]` which do NOT exist in the original wave. So, you can deem the values of `wave[-1]` and `wave[L]` as `0`.
- All the numbers in the new wave will be integers.

I have written the following code but not sure what are the issues exactly since the program keeps returning 0

```
def filter_wave(wave,times):
    new_wave = []
    for i in range(len(wave)):
        if wave[i-1] < wave[0]:
            return 0
        if wave[i+1] > len(wave):
            return 0
    new_wave = wave[i-1] * 0.2 + wave[i]*0.6 + wave[i+1]*0.2
    new_wave.insert(i,int(new_wave))
    return new_wave
```

Comment: Several problems.  Your if statements should not be RETURNING 0.  You just need to feed a zero into the convolution.  Plus, the question should not be `if wave[i-1] < wave[0]:`  That's fetching the wave values.  You want to check the index: `if i-1 < 0:` and `if i+1 > len(wave):`.  You don't need to use `insert`, just use `append`.  And you've used the `new_wave` variable for two purposes here; when you do `new_wave = wave[...`, you destroy the list you've been creating.

Answer (score 2):

There are better ways to do this, but this is parallel to your choices.

```
def filter_wave(wave,times):
    new_wave = []
    for i in range(len(wave)):
        if i == 0:
            prev = 0
        else:
            prev = wave[i-1]
        if i+1 >= len(wave):
            nxt = 0
        else:
            nxt = wave[i+1]
        new_wave.append( prev * 0.2 + wave[i] * 0.6 + nxt * 0.2 )
    return new_wave
```

Alternative, which handles the endpoints outside the loop, thereby making the loop simpler:

```
def filter_wave(wave,times):
    new_wave = []
    new_wave.append( wave[0] * 0.6 + wave[1] * 0.2 )
    for i in range(1, len(wave)-1):
        new_wave.append( wave[i-1] * 0.2 + wave[i] * 0.6 + wave[i+1] * 0.2 )
    new_wave.append( wave[-2] * 0.2 + wave[-1] * 0.6 )
    return new_wave
```

Comment: The key reason this is an improvement is that there's only one `return`.

Comment: Hi Tim, thank you for the quick response. If you don't mind, could you help in answering my quuery?

1/ could you explain why is the else statement **prev = wave[i-1]** and **next = wave[i+2]**

that's saying if i is not equal to 0, the previous number will be equal to 0. Else, if i is any other number, previous number will be wave[i-1]. can't seem to wrap my head around the logic for this would really appreciate your explanation thank you!

Comment: It is straightforward.  We're looking at position i.  If i is 0, it's the very first element, so the previous one must be 0.  Otherwise, we can use `element[i-1]`.  Similarly, if i is the final element, then the third part of the convolution will be 0.  Otherwise, it can be `element[i+1]`.

Comment: thank you for the very straightforward explanation, Tim! That makes things much clearer for me! Truly appreciate it! while on this, I've also tried adding a while statement so that the program will repeat the filtering n times to the wave accumulatively but it won't seem to work. Would appreciate your insight to the line I've added:


while times > 0:
            new_wave.append(int(prev * 0.2 + wave[i] * 0.6 + nxt * 0.2))

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if this will work.

```py
def filter_wave(wave, times):
    L = len(wave)
    new_wave = []

    for i in range(times):            
        for j in range(L):
            if j == 0:                        #wave[-1] = 0                          
                new_wave[j] = int(wave[j] * 0.6 + wave[j + 1] * 0.2)
            elif j == L - 1:                  #wave[L] = 0          
                new_wave[j] = int(wave[j - 1] * 0.2 + wave[j] * 0.6)
            else:
                new_wave[j] = int(wave[j - 1] * 0.2 + wave[j] * 0.6 + wave[j + 1] * 0.2)
            
    return new_wave
```

Comment: No, it won't, because you never add any elements to `new_wave`.  If you changed the assignments to `.append` calls, it would work.  Also, he never told us what `times` was for.  As a rule, saying "I wonder if this will work" does not quality as an answer to the question.